# Use a Github package for a R Github action

Tags: r, github, github-actions

I need to use a R package hosted on Github as a dependency of the R package I want to check with a Github action.

So in the **yaml** file I wrote the instructions to install the **remotes** package and then the needed Github package:

```yaml
      - name: Install remotes
        run: |
          Rscript -e "install.packages('remotes', repos='https://ftp.belnet.be/mirror/CRAN')"

      - name: Install gyro from Github
        run: |
          Rscript -e "remotes::install_github('stla/gyro')"

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          extra-packages: any::rcmdcheck
          needs: check

      - uses: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v2
```

This fails, the CRAN package is installed instead of the Github package. Maybe I don't write the instructions at the right position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, I had to change the order as follows:

```yaml
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          extra-packages: any::rcmdcheck
          needs: check

      - name: Install remotes
        run: |
          Rscript -e "install.packages('remotes', repos='https://ftp.belnet.be/mirror/CRAN')"

      - name: Install gyro from Github
        run: |
          Rscript -e "remotes::install_github('stla/gyro')"

      - uses: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v2
```

Comment: It's not something I do myself (as I prefer being clear and explicit in the yaml file) but my understanding is that with a proper `Remotes:` field in `DESCRIPTION` this happens automagically.