# Install a Github R package for a Github action

Tags: r, github, github-actions

I have [already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76642914/1100107) been able to install a Github package for a Github action. I followed the same process to install the `chromote` package (because I want to install the development version) but this fails with this message:

```
Run Rscript -e "remotes::install_github('rstudio/chromote')"
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Error: Error: Failed to install 'chromote' from GitHub:
  SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK: [api.github.com] SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.github.com'
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Would you know what does that mean, and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way. First I build the **chromote** package as a `tar.gz`. I put this `tar.gz` on my Github. Then in the Github action I install the **remotes** package and I use `install_url` to install **chromote**.

```yaml
   ......

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          extra-packages: any::rcmdcheck
          needs: check

      - name: Install remotes
        run: |
          Rscript -e "install.packages('remotes', repos='https://ftp.belnet.be/mirror/CRAN')"

      - name: Install chromote
        run: |
          Rscript -e "remotes::install_url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stla/giacR/main/inst/chromote_0.1.1.9001.tar.gz')"

      - uses: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v2
```